# SQL Stored Procedures vs .net code for CPU & RAM heavy work

Tags: c#, sql-server, performance

I'm processing a lot of stateless time based data in a (edit: Microsoft SQL Server) SQL database - for the sake of this question, it's basically IoT sensor data.  We've been graphing this data for customers and now they want us to do some analysis of the data, particularly pro-rating/interpolating values to get a estimated value for 15 minute boundaries, etc.

We're currently doing all of this in SQL stored procedures, mainly because the initial requirements were (and still are) query heavy rather then processor heavy.

We're now at the stage where our stored procedures start with a SELECT TOP 1 into variables, tons of conditional processing with floating point division followed by a single UPDATE or INSERT at the end.

This is all scheduled/non real time processing so we can call a script every minute or so if required.

Has anyone else had a similar problem, or done the analysis to compare Stored Procedures vs .net CLR vs .net console app?

Maybe the more important question is, am I likely to have a noticeable performance improvement by moving away from doing CPU heavy work inside stored procedures?

Comment: Is the sort of analysis your doing not suitable for say R? As for your question, I did a similar comparison a few years ago and in the end, if you're not working with large sets of data then C# code was quicker. We were able to aggregate all our data in SQL server and then have all the computational stuff done in C#. Was quicker than bringing raw data to C# and then aggregating it and then doing analysis as well as doing everything in SQL Server. Basically, join, group, etc in SQL Server and then do the rest in C#.

Comment: Procedural code is **highly vendor-specific** - so please add a tag to specify whether you're using `mysql`, `postgresql`, `sql-server`, `oracle` or `db2` - or something else entirely.

Comment: It largely depends on what kind of computations you do (that use just T-SQL variables, not the data in the tables). If you have few tight nested loops, then C# and C++ would be likely faster. As it stands, the question is too broad.